# What is the KeyOwnerProofSystem in BABE config?

Tags: babe, session, historical

In the pallet_babe config one can see the type `KeyOwnerProofSystem` as being set to Historical which is a reference to `pallet_session::historical`.

What functions does a `KeyProofSystem` serve? What is it "proving" and for whom?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say you have found an equivocation for Babe. Aka you are saying that Alice build two blocks on the same height in session 100. You will now need to prove to the runtime that there is an equivocation. You send the [proof](https://docs.rs/sp-consensus-slots/latest/sp_consensus_slots/struct.EquivocationProof.html) to the runtime. While the runtime checks the proof, it needs to ensure that Alice is really part of the validator set in session 100. This check is done using the `KeyProofSystem`. In case of `pallet_session::historical`, it records all the validator sets for the last X sessions (can be configured) to prove these kind of requests.